# Prove $\limsup\{a_n\}\ge 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\{a_n\}$, a bounded sequence such that $a_n>0 \forall n>0$. Let:
>   $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = 1$$
>   Prove that $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\ge 1$.

**My attempt:**
It is given that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = 1$.
Therefore, if the sequence is $a_n=1 \forall n>0$ then we've finished.
Otherwise, one term must be greater then one, while the other smaller then one.

Hence, There are two sub-sequences; One bounded from above and converges to $1$, and the other bounded bellow and converges to $1$ (because we know $a_n$ is bounded).

In any case, $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ as requested.

I think my proof is a bit handwaving. How can I "polish" it (Making it more rigorous)? I think I need to explain why there must be two sequences such that. Can you help me with that?  Thanks!

Comment: Your "one term must be greater then one, while the other smaller then one" is a non-sequitur. Consider for example $a_n=1+\frac1n$.

Comment: If you are trying to prove that $a_n=1$ for some $n>N$, I don't think that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\lim \sup a_n< 1$, then $a_n<1$ for very large $n$.

Comment: I got it. and then, there's no way that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = 1$. Right? A contradiction.